# Showing that $\csc\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)$ does not have a Laurent series convergent in $B^{\circ}(0,r)$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, laurent-series

> I am trying to show that the function, $$f(z)=\csc\left(\frac{1}{z}\right),$$
>   does not have a Laurent series about $0$ that converges to $f$ in $B^{\circ}(0,r)$ for any $r>0$.

I thought I could solve this problem by contradiction. For this, I compute the series for $\csc(z)$, as $$\csc(z)=\frac{1}{z}+\frac{z}{6}+\frac{7}{360}z^3+..$$
This means that $$\csc\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)=z+\frac{1}{6 \ z}+\frac{7}{360 \ z^3}+..$$
It was at this point that I could not see a contradiction, as the series appears to converge in $0<|z|<r$.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The function is not defined at the points $\frac 1 {n\pi}$.

Comment: But wouldn't a Laurent series still exist? E.g. in the punctured ball $0<|z|<\frac{1}{\pi}$.

Comment: $\frac 1 {n\pi} \to 0$.

Comment: I don't quite understand. Can't a Laurent series (unlike a Taylor series) exist in a punctured ball? I'm thinking of $0<|z|<\frac{1}{\pi}$. Isn't the function holomorphic here and hence admits a power series.

Comment: Laurent series is defined only around isolated singularities. $0$ is not an isolated singularity of this function.

Comment: Is $z=0$ an essential singularity? If so, shouldn't it admit a power series?

Comment: Classification of singularities in Complex Analysis is only for isolated singularities. None of the theorems in CA about singularities can be applied to a singularity unless the function is well defined and analytic in some disk around the point minus that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Laurent series must always converge on some annulus. In your case, you want it to converge on $B(0,r)\setminus\{0\}$, for some $r>0$. But that's no possible, since $\csc$ has a pole at every number of the form $\dfrac1{n\pi}$ ($n\in\mathbb N$), and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac1{n\pi}=0.$

Comment: What does $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n\pi}=0$ signify?

Comment: @Bell That the sequence $\left(\frac1{n\pi}\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges to $0$.

Comment: It's difficult to visualize. I draw the punctured ball $0<|z|<\frac{1}{pi}$ and I can't see why the function would not have a Laurent series in this region.

Comment: @Bell Because $\frac1{2\pi}$ belongs to that region and $\lim_{z\to\frac1{2\pi}}\lvert \csc z\rvert=+\infty$.

Comment: wow a lightbulb just went off haha Sorry it took so long, I'm very tired. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Bell I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\sigma$ be the set of singularities of $f$ on $\mathbb C$.

Clearly,
$$\sigma=\left\{\frac1{n\pi}\right\}\qquad{n\in\mathbb Z\setminus \{0\}}$$

You can easily prove $0$ is a limit point of $\sigma$.

If some Laurent series converges to $f$ in $B^\circ(0,r)$ where $r>0$, then $$B^\circ(0,r)\cap \sigma=\emptyset$$ which is contradictory to the definition of limit point.